# Drop down list produces defined range list in an area

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-docs

I have a drop down list in E8 that has several item categories in it and below the drop down box I have a square B9 to H24.  How can I with the Level 3 drop down selection show a defined named range (!P:P) in the box between b9 and h24

Comment: Please provide more details. Or share a copy of your sheet.

Comment: how do i post a copy?

Comment: [Share a file publicly](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308873?hl=en)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1msXEdUvR2mH1sFPeAdwk8dEdpyVwvBQbEDzXnBb5J8k/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: In the copy of bloodweb purchases tab i have a drop down list and am attempting to based on the dropdown list show the results in the box below it

Comment: Where is the drop down box? What is your expected output? Please provide the information required for this problem.

Comment: Copy of bloodweb purchases, cell e8 has the drop down box and based on the drop down selected id like to list the named ranged cells verticically then going over to the next column when the first column reached the bottom of the box.  The only difference would be if the user selects "Perks i'd like it to show an entire list but skipping a column

Comment: Understood. The drop down list is not shown because it is view-only.

Comment: I changed it to commentor, would that fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could refer to named range dynamically like this:

`=INDIRECT(E8)`

---

To 'split' a column into a specified 'box area':

```
=TRANSPOSE(INDEX(VLOOKUP(SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(COUNTA(P:P)/ROWS(B9:H24)),ROWS(B9:H24),1,1),{ROW(P:P),P:P},2,FALSE)))
```

Comment: could i chat with you on hangouts to make this easier?

Comment: For instance one of the options in the drop down list is Level 3, I have a defined named range called Level3 could I use an if statement like =if e8="Level 3", Level3? but then I dont know how to make i stay within the box either.

Comment: Edit permission is required to view those details. Also, please edit your question to provide minimum required information such as: i) Cell of drop down, ii) range of named range, iii) range to output, iv) expect output, etc.

Comment: Edit permission granted, drop down list is in E8, would like the run down to the bottom of the box starting at b9 and going down to b24 then going back up to c9...etc.  If you could do it for the Level 3 drop down selection just so I can see how you did it, i should be able to do he rest.  The named range for the level 3 list is !P:P

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I have got what you want to do. Could you please edit and add these the your question, such that others can also know it?

Comment: Updated. Please check.

Comment: So perfect, thankyou so much.  I am gonna post one more question but I will post it as a seperate question.  Thankyou again!!

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: I voted up on it but it says i need 15 reputation

Comment: The new question is up if you would like to look at it.